# Firebase Firestore - How to query by timestamp date?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use a query that compares the date today as follows:

```
let today = Date()

cardRef.where('date', '=', today).get().then(function(cardSnapshot) {
  cardSnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    cards[doc.id] = doc.data()
  })
})
```

Using this query, no data is fetched, is the format of the date wrong? The 'date' property is a timestamp from Firestore

Comment: The 'date' property is a timestamp from Firestore -- paste that here and console the value of `today`

Comment: What is the value of `today`? Please responde with @.